# bitmap image printing using axiohm usbcomm dll

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, thermal-printer, barcode-printing

I am using an Axiohm thermal printer for printing POS receipt(USBCOMM.dll for communication). Currently, i am able to print the required details along with an image(.bmp file). Now i need to use a new image instead of the existing image. The new image contains barcode. 
When i try printing the new image, all i get is some garbage values. Below is the code that i use. Same code works with old image but not with the new image. Is there any format for image that i need to follow.

```
Dim filepath As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Resources\PrinterDlls\unnamed.bmp"

            Using fs = New FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
                Dim inpt As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length) {}
                inpt(0) = &H1F
                fs.Read(inpt, 1, CInt(fs.Length))
                Dim ok As Boolean = Usb_WritePort(True, inpt, inpt.Length, written, IntPtr.Zero)
                If Not ok OrElse written <> inpt.Length Then
                    Throw New Exception("USB write failed")
                End If
            End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing that i am answering my own question. I searched for sometime to resolve and raised the question. Soon after, i came across this video in youtube that explain the bitmap image to create for thermal printing

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdB33eWLjgU

Basically, you need to ensure 3 things while creating the image:
1. 8-bit
2. Greyscale
3. Save as .bmp

And the new image will work like a charm while printing. Also ensure the width is less than the paper width.